# Desktop sharing from Ubuntu 18.04 to Mac

Tags: 18.04, mac, remote-desktop, vnc

I've been searching the web sporadically for a month or two trying to figure out how to remote share my Ubuntu desktop to my Mac laptop. I've been able to connect over VNC and over RDP but neither one works enough to be even serviceable. I either get a blank window, or maybe just one window. I've run through a dozen articles on various services and whether to use SSH or not etc.

So bottom line, what's a dead simple way to share my Ubuntu 18.04 desktop to Mac? The simplest way I found so far is to use "Desktop Sharing" but it doesn't work on 18.04 as attested by the half dozen reviews of Desktop Sharing in the Ubuntu Software App.

Answer (score 0):

What about TeamViewer? It's completely free for personal use, and you can remote share via Linux, Windows, MacOS, Chrome OS, mobile, etc.